# Script to continuously follow kubectl get pods

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, kubectl

I'm trying to build a script that can follow(-f) `kubectl get pods` see a realtime update when I make any changes/delete pods on Ubuntu server.

What could be the easiest/efficient way to do so?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can just use

```
kubectl get pod <your pod name> -w
```

whenever any update/change/delete happen to the pod, you will see the update.

You can also use

```
watch -n 1 kubectl get  pod <your pod name>
```

This will continuously run `kubectl get pod ...` with 1 seconds interval. So, you will see latest state.

Comment: If somebody wants to see all the pods and filter them using grep command, you can do it like 
watch -n 1 'kubectl get pods | grep my_filter'

Comment: Thank you!

I've been using the `-w` flag for a while but its not a good user experience if you just want to the current state of multiple things.

Been getting tired of pressing up then enter in the terminal.

`watch -n .5 kubectl get pods` such a better ux.

Answer (score 9):

Adding a `-w` or `--watch` to all your `kubectl get [resource]s` command makes the result notified of each creation, modification, or deletion of that resource.
i.e `kubectl get pod [pod_name] -w` or `kubectl get nodes --watch`